# Why does copper(II) sulfate or iron(III) nitrate work as a catalyst for the iodate variant of the Iodine Clock?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox

In the iodine clock reaction ([iodate variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_clock_reaction)), the reaction of iodate and bisulfite ions apparently is the rate-determining step. I was wondering if $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and $\ce{Fe^3+}$ will act as homogeneous catalysts in the following rate-determining step (or so wikipedia claims): $\ce{IO^-_3  + 3 HSO^-_3 -> I− + 3HSO^-_4}$.

The steps in the iodate variant:

$\ce{IO^-_3 + 3 HSO^-_3 -> I− + 3HSO^-_4}$

$\ce{IO^-_3 + 5 I− + 6 H+ -> 3 I2 + 3 H2O}$

$\ce{I2 + HSO^-_3 + H2O → 2 I− + HSO^-_4 + 2 H+}$

$\ce{iodine + iodide + starch -> blue/black complex}$

In control experiments, in absence of a catalyst added, the reaction took $\pu{20 s}$ to finish.  However, in presence of copper it took $\pu{10 s}$, and if iron was added it took like $\pu{6 s}$. So there **must be something happening between the metal catalyst and the rate-determining step**, but I just simply cant find out why. This means that the **catalysts must be reacting with the reagents in the rate-determining step.**

The famous reaction of $\ce{2I− + S2O^2-_8 -> I2 + 2 SO^2-_4}$, where $\ce{Fe^3+}$ and $\ce{Fe^2+}$ can catalyze that reaction. **Therefore something similar must be happening in the iodate variant too right?**

However, from the countless research I've done, both $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and $\ce{Fe^3+}$ doesn't react with both of the reactants in the rate-determining step. But both $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and $\ce{Fe^3+}$ will react with $\ce{I-}$, **which is not in the rate-determining step.**

Perhaps I'm not looking hard enough :( , but maybe there are experts in here that may help? help would be significantly appreciated!

Comment: For future reference: chemistry.se permits to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) to edit chemical equations in bodies of questions, answers, and comments.  Because it is a specialty not all browsers process equally well, don't use in the headers of questions, though.  Here: especially the rendering of more complex ions as e.g., $\ce{S2O^{2-}_8}$ becomes easier to read.

Comment: Generally, oxidation of one anion by another anion may be slow due coulombic repulsion. And it is generally catalyzed by cations of transition metals with more oxidations states, with reduction potential nearby the ones of both major redox systems. The notorious case is oxidation of oxalic acid by permanganate, autocatalyzed by Mn(II) ions.

Comment: Thank you you @Poutnik I am aware of this, but HOW does Cu2+ and Fe3+ work in this case?

Comment: @Buttonwood Im so sorry but I do not understand you mean here :(

Comment: Fe(III)/Cu(II) oxidizes I- and IO3- oxidizes Fe(II)/Cu(I). Also at least Fe(III) would oxidize S(IV), it has higher redox potential than iodine/iodide.

Comment: @Metron In the web browser I currently use (Firefox), the rendering of e.g. sulfate, hydrogensulfite/bisulfit, or peroxodisulfate did not process well the charges. Have a look at the [revision history](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/175921/revisions) for version 2, option «side-by-side» (rendering).  With characters already small (because by their design already prepares them to be a super- or subscript (see option «side-by-side markdown», same page and version, there still were some issues (e.g., negative charge on hydrogensulfite/bisulfite), too.

Comment: @Poutnik But the iodide and iodate is in the 2nd step, which is not the rate-determining step according to wikipedia. So are you saying that instead of the catalysts reacting with the rate-determining step(Step 1), it is for some reason reacting with Step 2?

Comment: The 1st, rate determining slow step is about I- generation from IO3-.  This is bypassed by metal catalytic system.

Comment: @Poutnik but didnt you mention: "Fe(III)/Cu(II) oxidizes I- and IO3- oxidizes Fe(II)/Cu(I)." Only IO3- is in Step 1(rate-determining step). I- is the product of Step 1, and catalysts do not react with products to my knowledge

Comment: Catalysts accelerate both forward and backward reactions. If the Haber-Bosch catalyst accelerates 3 H2 + N2 -> 2 NH3, it accelerates  2 NH3 -> 3 H2 + N2 too. Catalyst do not shift the equilibrium, they just accelerate reaching the equilibrium.  // Fe(III) oxidizes hydrogensulphite, Fe(II) reduces iodate.

Comment: @Poutnik That is very interesting indeed, does "Catalysts accelerate both forward and backward reactions" this only happen in reversible reactions like the do you mentioned? If so, Is there any souces that elaborate on your point further? I would love to look more into it. 

Another question: So what will "Fe(III) oxidizes hydrogensulphite(aka bisulfite)" form? I cant seem to find the half reaction of HSO3- losing electrons in the Standard Cell Potential chart. If I were to guess then it must be HSO4-? but then again how does gaining 1 electron lead to a completely new chemical formula?